# Automatic encryption/decryption: detect file is closed in Mate/Gnome application

Tags: shell, filesystems, gnome, inotify, mate

I'm writing a bash script to automatically decrypt file for editing and encrypt it back after file is closed. File type could be any: plain-text, office document, etc. I am on Linux Mint with Mate.

I'm stuck: can't reliably detect if file was closed in application so that script can proceed to encrypting it back and removing decrypted version.

The first version of the script simply used vim with text files. Script was calling it directly and hadn't been going any further until vim was closed. Now as I want to be able to do so with other files, I tried the following things:

xdg-open: exits immediately after calling the application associated with file type. Thus script continues and does no good.

xdg-open's modified function for calling an associated app: runs it inside the current script so now I see program exit. Works only if the application hasn't been running already. If it has, then new process is finished and script continues.

So what I am trying to do now is to watch somehow that file was closed in already running application. Currently experimenting with pluma/gedit and inotifywait. It doesn't work either - instantly after file was opened it detects *CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE* event.

Is it at all possible to detect this without specific hooks for different applications? Possibly some X hooks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lsof to determine if a file is opened by a process:

```
myFile="/home/myUser/myFile"
/usr/sbin/lsof "$myFile" | grep "$myFile"
```

You can use a 1 second loop and wait until the lsof response is empty. I have used this to help prevent a script from opening a newly discovered file that is still being written or downloaded.

Not all processes hold a file open while they are using it. For example, vim holds open a temporary file (/home/myUser/.myFile.swp) and may only open the real file when loading or saving.

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like this.

```
decrypt "TheFile"&
pluma "TheFile"
encrypt "TheFile"
```

The `&` at the end of a line will execute the line then fall through to Pluma. The script will pause until pluma closes.

I could offer more help if you post your script.